# How to show not null column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table. There are For example I have 100 columns in this table. I want to get only the filled ones from these columns. how do i get this without checking the column names individually for null?

I can do it like this for a single column

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE id = 436432
AND name IS NOT NULL;
```

Since the number of columns is too many, I do not want to do as follows. what can I do?

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE id = 436432
AND id IS NOT NULL
AND name IS NOT NULL
AND surname IS NOT NULL
AND email IS NOT NULL
AND phone IS NOT NULL
AND adress IS NOT NULL
.
.
.
;
```

Comment: I am afraid if you create a table with 100 columns you then have to deal with a table with 100 columns

Comment: Also, that query makes little sense, do you want to see what the customeer with `id=436432` contains or not. Yours will most likely not show this row as I have to assume one or more of the columns must be NULL or why bother testing all the columns for NULL

Comment: I guess you can keep a generated column which operates on those 100 columns and value is true if there are no null values else false. Then you can select only those which have generated column as true, thus reducing the size of your query.

Comment: was about to suggest the same thing, an alternative is to maintain a separate column on insert/update that you set separately and can check in your query.

Comment: What would you do if you faced such a situation? Can you give an example as sql?

Comment: I would probably choose to add a generated column of a `case expression` that checks each column and returns a single true/false. you then check this one computed column.

Comment: How often do you have to run this query?

Comment: `I want to get only the filled ones from these columns` you cannot do that with a where clause as the where clause determines if a row is included in the resultset or not. In fact, you cannot just return the columns that contain non-null values only with a single call as you have to provide the exact list of columns in the select list. You would need to first determine which columns are null first then dynamically construct another sql statement that retrieves the non-null columns only. Probably not too efficient. All solutions so far discuss how to determine if a row has only non-null values.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a generated column as follows

```
ALTER TABLE `customer` 
ADD COLUMN `not_null` BOOLEAN GENERATED ALWAYS AS (created_by IS NOT NULL AND created_at IS NOT NULL) AFTER `name_of_last_column`;
```

replace the expression in `ALWAYS AS ()` with the AND of your 100 columns.
And then query as

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `not_null` = 1;
```

You may choose to keep the generated column as virtual or stored.